# how to add javascript and css files to magentomodule

Tags: javascript, css, magento, module

I created a magento module a simple one.

Now I want to custom css and javascript files and use it i n my module.
I tried to add files into skin directory but I don't undrestand how this works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, your layout file should be placed in app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/layout/.
Second. If you want to add the css and js files only in the grouped and simple product pages don't use the `<default>` layout handle.
Make your layout look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <my_handle><!-- declare a custom handle so you won't duplicate the code -->
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>vendor/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>vendor/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </my_handle>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple><!-- layout handle for simple products -->
        <update handle="my_handle" /> <!-- include the handle you declared above -->
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped><!-- layout handle for grouped products -->
        <update handle="my_handle" /> <!-- include the handle you declared above -->
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
</layout>
```